# userspace-kernel shared memory with mmap works strange on multi-thread

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap

I'm currently making shared memory between userspace to kernel.

The following code is simple version of my mmap method.

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    RxFrame[j] = kmalloc(4096*6, GFP_KERNEL);
    npages = (4096*6 - 1)/(PAGE_SIZE) + 1;
    for(i = 0; i < npages*PAGE_SIZE; i += PAGE_SIZE){
        printk("RxFrame[%d] PAGE_SIZE is %d\n", j, PAGE_SIZE);
        SetPageReserved(virt_to_page(RxFrame[j] + i));
    }
}

static int my_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma){
    unsigned long pfn = virt_to_phys(RxFrame[index]);
    ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, pfn>>PAGE_SHIFT, len, vma->vm_page_prot);
    if (ret < 0) {
        pr_err("could not map the address area\n");
        return -EIO;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And following is my userspace application code which mmap used.

```
FRAME *RxFrame[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if( (RxFrame[i] = mmap(0, 4096*6, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd[i], 0)) == NULL ){
        printf("mmap error\n");
        return 0;
    }
}


auto DoReceive = [&](const int index){
    // read RxFrame[index][0].data 
}

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    thread[i] = std::thread(DoReceive , i);
    usleep(1000);   
}
```

My purpose was making three kernel buffers which dedicated data(different data will store in different kernel buffer) will store and use them with mmap in userspace with multi-thread.

when just one kernel buffer is used(data stored in just one kernel buffer), I can read RxFrame[index][0].data very well.

But when three kernel buffer is used(different data stored in separate kernel buffer), I can only read the first transmitted data.. for example if RxFrame[0]'s buffer received data, I can read RxFrame[0][0].data but can't read RxFrame[1][0].data and RxFrame[2][0].data..

Strange thing is that when received data is quite a lot at few moment, I can read RxFrame[1][0].data and RxFrame[2][0].data which looks like cached result!

I used volatile and other mmap option but I can't figure out why my mapped memory works like cached in multi-thread.

Any help will be thanks!

userspace-kernel shared memory with mmap works strange on multi-thread

Comment: How are you making the user address struct vma and passing it to the kernel?

Comment: "The following code is simple version of my mmap systemcall." - It is not a **system call**. It is a "**method**" `mmap` in the `file_operations` structure for your character device (or other special file object). System call `mmap` calls this method when it need to process `mmap` request for your file.

Comment: I thought userspace mmap systemcall will do make vma things and Thanks for correct me about the term!